# Load a keytab from HDFS

Tags: java, hdfs, kerberos, keytab

I want to use Oozie with a Java Action which needs to use Kerberos. 
I have my keytab in HDFS. How could I say that the file is in HDFS?

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");     
 UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
 UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(kerberosPrincipal, kerberosKeytab);
```

I have tried with a path like `hdfs://xxxx:8020/tmp/myKeytab.keytab` and I set `conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://server:8020");` as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: For security reasons, storing keytabs in HDFS seems like a bad idea

Comment: I know, but if I want to execute some JDBC connection to Hive2 from a java action in Oozie, how could I do it?. It seems that delegation token doesn't work or I didn't get it to work.

Comment: *"storing keytabs in HDFS seems like a bad idea"* -- why would it be worse than a web server storing its RSA private key on the local filesystem? Or a user storing its SSH private key on his/her PC? With Kerberos enabled, HDFS has exactly the same access control mechanism as a local filesystem (cf. `chmod` and `setfacl`).

Comment: `loginUserFromKeytab( )` expects a local file, you must download it inside your local container first. Easy with Oozie.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter HDFS is not a local file system. There are also, by default, 3 replicas of that keytab in the data nodes that are not encrypted at rest. That triples the likelihood someone will find them. Would you place 3 copies of an SSH private key on a distributed file system? Probably not.

Comment: Honestly: I trust my corporate PC much less than I trust a kerberized Hadoop cluster deep inside a corporate Data Center. And password-based security is a joke. So, yes, I will put a SSH private key on a distributed FS any day. (And I will also check the ACLs immediately after that)

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop delegation tokens work only for YARN and HDFS, and they expire after 7 days. For all other services -- especially HBase (via ZooKeeper), HiveServer2 (directly or via ZooKeeper), Hive Metastore (inside Hive CLI) -- you need to authenticate directly. For long-running services, you need to re-authenticate periodically to renew the delegation token *(if you rely on Slider, it does that automatically for you)*

**Option 1**: ask Oozie to generate the appropriate `<credential>` for your Action. I wish it really worked out-of-the-box and/or that it was better documented -- Hive works like a charm; not so with HBase; never tried Hive2 so I can't be sure.

**Option 2**: ask Oozie to download your custom keytab file from HDFS *(you took care of restricting access to that keytab, didn't you???)* to the CWD of your Launcher container with a `<file>` option, then generate your credentials all by yourself.

With a Java action it will be option 2.

Comment: UPDATE - nowadays HBase, Hive Metastore and HiveServer2 all have their specific flavor of delegation token. Oozie (and Spark) can handle authentication for the jobs (executors) they spawn.